# Back button becomes disabled when using onWillPop and it happens in the first build of apps

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, navigator

I am using `onWillPop` to navigate the user to my homescreen when user clicks back button from their phone, here is part of the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return HomeAssesmentScreen();
            },
          ),
        );
        return Future.value(true);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
```

However, the problem is that I can not click my back button. Back button becomes disabled and I can not navigate user to another screen. Is there a way to re-activate the back button?

Comment: This should work, I don't find any issues in above code which should disable back button

Comment: back button is disable because you hasn't any screen in your stack ... when you push a screen you can pop it , and your function call before pop.

Comment: Hi @jitsm555,mohandesR... I dont know what happen at that time, but when I keep clicking back button from my phone... it doesn't navigate me to screen before... and that's only happen in the first build of my apps, after I close the apps and re open the apps, I can use back button from my phone

Answer (score 1):

You use Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement() method.
This method just replace current page on Stack of pages with your pushed MaterialPageRoute().

If you want a back button, then use method push() instead of pushReplacement().

Answer (score 1):

this should work:
probably you're missing the async / await

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    await Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return HomeAssesmentScreen();
            },
          ),
        );
    return true;
  }


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
        child: Scaffold(
```